# OpenVPN tunnel up but no traffic from LAN to VPN

Tags: openvpn, shorewall

The HeadOffice subnet is 192.168.2.0/24. OpenVPN server & shorewall on same box - acting as a gateway

AWS subnet is 10.9.1.0/24. Openvpn Client configured for VPN access

Tunnel is up and I can ping & SSH from AWS to Headoffice

On the HeadOffice box, I see:

```
tun0 inet addr:10.1.0.1 P-t-P:10.1.0.2 Mask:255.255.255.255
```

No routes injected. I manually injected the route but that did not help

On AWS OpenVPN Box I see:

```
tun0 inet addr:10.1.0.94 P-t-P:10.1.0.93 Mask:255.255.255.255

192.168.2.0 10.1.0.93 255.255.255.0 UG 0 0 0 tun0
```

I can ping 10.1.0.94 from both locations for cannot ping 10.1.0.93 from any location.

What am I missing here?

**VPN2Remote**

```
local 76.9.1.2
proto udp
dev tun
server 10.1.0.0 255.255.255.0
push "route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 10.9.1.0 255.255.255.0"
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status vpnstats.log
ca keys/ca.crt
comp-lzo
verb 3
mute 20
cert keys/headofficefw.crt
key keys/headofficefw.key
```

**VPN2HeadOffice**

```
client
cd /etc/openvpn
dev tun
proto udp
remote 76.9.1.2
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status vpnstats.log
ca keys/ca.crt
cert keys/awsfw.crt
key keys/awsfw.key
ns-cert-type server
comp-lzo
verb 3
mute 20
push "route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 10.9.1.0 255.255.255.0"
route 10.9.1.0 255.255.255.0
```

Answer (score 0):

OpenVPN is designed in such a way, 101.0.93 will not ping. Assigned IP address is 10.1.0.94 which pings without any issue.
Basically routes are being pushed from OpenVPN Server if we mention `push routes` in server.conf
On the server side LAn to reach AWS LAN network, we need to add an entry in server.conf like:
`route add -net 10.9.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.1.0.94 dev tun0`
Also enable ipv4 forwarding and add `topology subnet` in server.conf to allow Server to talk to Clients.
Please post your server.conf and client.conf

Comment: Thanks @Samudrala. I followed your suggestion and the route gets created on the server side too. I am yet unable to ping the remote machine. Do you think it might be shorewall or is it by design that I cannot ping the ip of the remove server

Comment: If possible could you please post your configuration files to check what could be the issue. I have successfully implemented OpenVPN which takes two way communication between Server-Client.

Comment: I believe below entries are missing in your server.conf: `client-to-client`. Also add same subnets used for push route as `route route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0`. Use the same command and add other routes too.